# Download selected records by using checkbox in ALV output

Tags: abap, alv

I am using this code to download selected records.  But I am unable to do that.  What am I doing wrong?

```
FORM ZUCOMM USING LV_OKCODE TYPE SY-UCOMM
             SEL_FIELD TYPE SLIS_SELFIELD.


CASE LV_OKCODE .

    WHEN 'DOWN' .
*   REFRESH IT_MARA1.
IF FLAG = 'X'.


         lOOP AT it_mara INTO wa_mara."  WHERE CHECK  = 'X'.
*
        wa_mara1-matnr =  wa_mara-matnr.
        wa_mara1-MTART = wa_mara-MTART.
        wa_mara1-MATKL = wa_mara-MATKL.

        APPEND wa_mara1 TO it_mara1.
                 ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Stop shouting. Capitals are not required and make it hard to read

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly you want to do, but if you want find in internal table for alv some record use someting like this my code:

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  atusercommand
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*      -->UCOMM      text
*      -->SELFIELD   text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM ATUSERCOMMAND USING UCOMM LIKE SY-UCOMM
                SELFIELD TYPE SLIS_SELFIELD.
  CASE UCOMM.
    WHEN '&IC1'." On click
        PERFORM ME_CALL_DETAIL USING SELFIELD.
    WHEN 'HIST'." Button
        PERFORM ME_CALL_DETAIL USING SELFIELD.
  ENDCASE.

ENDFORM.                    "atusercommand

FORM ME_CALL_DETAIL USING SELFIELD.
  READ TABLE GT_ALV WITH key CHECK  = 'X' INTO wt_pom.
  "some logic
ENDFORM.
```

If i want access selected row I usual use this:

```
READ TABLE GT_ALV4 INTO LS_ALV4 INDEX U_PSELFIELD-TABINDEX.
```